# How can get user info?

Tags: bixby

How can get the user name is Bixby providing any information about the user like his name?

I tried to add *bixby-user-id-access* and *user-profile-access* to use **$vivContext** to get some information but there is name for user. Also i tried to pass **self.GetSelf** but the result returned was empty and there is no user information.

```
computed-input (self) { 
      type (self.Self)
      min (Optional) max (One)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: self.Self
          route: self.GetSelf
        }
      }
}
```

```
property (self) {
    type (self.Self)
    min (Required) max (One)
}
```

[The value of self property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5IGC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$vivContext** does not contain such information. Please check [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions#passing-user-context-information) to see what **$vivContext** contains and how to access it in JS.

It is the correct approach to use viv.self library. To access you need **user-profile-access** permission. Read more about viv.self library [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.self).

Please follow this example, developer needs setup their profile first on a Samsung phone. For developers not yet have a Samsung phone, one can try to get familiar with the structure by using viv.self.GetImaginarySelf. The name will be "Hi Bixby" when using viv.self.GetImaginarySelf.

You can also download and try the sample capsule provide in [this KB article](https://bixbydevelopers.zendesk.com/knowledge/articles/360042116834)

```
action (GetAllNames) {
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  type (Search)
  collect {
    computed-input (self) {
      type (self.Self)
      min (Optional) max (One)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: self.Self
          route: self.GetImaginarySelf // for developers has NO Samsung device
          // route: self.GetSelf // for release
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (TextName)
}
```

And in linked JS in endpoints file, do this.

```
module.exports.function = function getAllNames (self) {
  var rslt = []
  rslt.push ("John")
  rslt.push ("Jane")
  if (self == null) {
    rslt.push ("NULL")
  }
  else {
    rslt.push(self.nameInfo.structuredName)
  }
  return rslt;
}
```

You should be able to see the name in result view. 
[image]

You should also be able to check other field of returned viv.self.Self structure in debugger window. 
[image]

Comment: Can you see this result it's almost empty? https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5IGC.png

Comment: because that is your own self property, not the computed from viv.self.Self. Copy the action, copy the JS, link them in endpoints. you should be able to see similar result.

Comment: Should i add any property in the action concept if yes what the type of that property? In your case the Concept is **TextName**. if you can share it with me

Comment: can you share your capsule because i tried to copy action and JS file but still i'm having a empty Self
This is result:
Generic Error
TypeError: Cannot read property "structuredName" from undefined

Comment: bixby.pdss.ProfileResult
   resultCode: PP_0002
   resultMessage: No Contents

Comment: Please let me know if you ever setup the account on a Bixby enabled mobile device. You can also down and try the sample capsule provide in https://bixbydevelopers.zendesk.com/knowledge/articles/360042116834/

Comment: Thanks self.GetImaginarySelf solved my problem. Please edit you answer and your helpful comment in the sample capsule
// route: self.GetImaginarySelf // for developers has NO Samsung device

Comment: Thank you for the note. Answered updated. Please accept the answer so it might help more developers.